# PySpark DataFrame change column of string to array before using explode

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column called **event_data** in `json` format in my spark DataFrame, after reading it using `from_json`, I get this schema:

```python
root
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- af_content_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- af_currency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- af_order_id: long (nullable = true)
```

I only need `af_content_id` from this column. This attribute can be of different formats:

a String

an Integer

a List of Int and Str. eg `['ghhjj23','123546',12356]`

None (sometimes event_data doesn't contain `af_content_id`)

I want to use `explode` function in order to return a new row for each element in `af_content_id` when it is of format **List**. But as when I apply it, I get an error:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

def get_content_id(column):
    return column.af_content_id

df_transf_1 = df_transf_1.withColumn(
    "products_basket", 
    get_content_id(df_transf_1.event_data)
)

df_transf_1 = df_transf_1.withColumn(
    "product_id",
    explode(df_transf_1.products_basket)
)
```

> cannot resolve 'explode(`products_basket`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not StringType;

I know the reason, it's because of the different types that the field `af_content_id` may contain, but I don't know how to resolve it. Using `pyspark.sql.functions.array()` directly on the column doesn't work because it become array of array and explode will not produce the expected result.

A sample code to reproduce the step that I'm stuck on:

```python
import pandas as pd

arr = [
    ['b5ad805c-f295-4852-82fc-961a88',12732936],
    ['0FD6955D-484C-4FC8-8C3F-DA7D28',['Gklb38','123655']],
    ['0E3D17EA-BEEF-4931-8104','12909841'],
    ['CC2877D0-A15C-4C0A-AD65-762A35C1',[12645715, 12909837, 12909837]]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns = ['user_id','products_basket'])

df = df[['user_id','products_basket']].astype(str)
df_transf_1 = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

I'm looking for a way to convert **products_basket** to one only possible format: an **Array** so that when I apply `explode`, it will contain one id per row.

Comment: The reason is that `af_content_id1` is a `StringType`, which can't be exploded. It may *look* like sometimes a list and sometimes a string, but it's actually always a string. There may be workarounds for this- please provide a small [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples) with your desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are starting with a DataFrame like:

```python
df_transf_1.show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
#|user_id                         |products_basket               |
#+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
#|b5ad805c-f295-4852-82fc-961a88  |12732936                      |
#|0FD6955D-484C-4FC8-8C3F-DA7D28  |['Gklb38', '123655']          |
#|0E3D17EA-BEEF-4931-8104         |12909841                      |
#|CC2877D0-A15C-4C0A-AD65-762A35C1|[12645715, 12909837, 12909837]|
#+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

where the `products_basket` column is a `StringType`:

```python
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
# |-- products_basket: string (nullable = true)
```

You can't call `explode` on `products_basket` because it's not an array or map.

One workaround is to remove any leading/trailing square brackets and then split the string on `", "` (comma followed by a space). This will convert the string into an array of strings.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace, split
df_transf_new= df_transf_1.withColumn(
    "products_basket",
    split(regexp_replace(col("products_basket"), r"(^\[)|(\]$)|(')", ""), ", ")
)

df_transf_new.show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
#|user_id                         |products_basket               |
#+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
#|b5ad805c-f295-4852-82fc-961a88  |[12732936]                    |
#|0FD6955D-484C-4FC8-8C3F-DA7D28  |[Gklb38, 123655]              |
#|0E3D17EA-BEEF-4931-8104         |[12909841]                    |
#|CC2877D0-A15C-4C0A-AD65-762A35C1|[12645715, 12909837, 12909837]|
#+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

The regular expression pattern matches any of the following:

- `(^\[)`: An opening square bracket at the start of the string
- `(\]$)`: A closing square bracket at the end of the string
- `(')`: Any single quote (because your strings are quoted)

and replaces these with an empty string.

This assumes that your data does not contain any needed single quotes or square brackets inside the `product_basket`.

After the `split`, the schema of the new DataFrame is:

```python
df_transf_new.printSchema()
#root
# |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
# |-- products_basket: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Now you can call `explode`:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df_transf_new.withColumn("product_id", explode("products_basket")).show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------------------+------------------------------+----------+
#|user_id                         |products_basket               |product_id|
#+--------------------------------+------------------------------+----------+
#|b5ad805c-f295-4852-82fc-961a88  |[12732936]                    |12732936  |
#|0FD6955D-484C-4FC8-8C3F-DA7D28  |[Gklb38, 123655]              |Gklb38    |
#|0FD6955D-484C-4FC8-8C3F-DA7D28  |[Gklb38, 123655]              |123655    |
#|0E3D17EA-BEEF-4931-8104         |[12909841]                    |12909841  |
#|CC2877D0-A15C-4C0A-AD65-762A35C1|[12645715, 12909837, 12909837]|12645715  |
#|CC2877D0-A15C-4C0A-AD65-762A35C1|[12645715, 12909837, 12909837]|12909837  |
#|CC2877D0-A15C-4C0A-AD65-762A35C1|[12645715, 12909837, 12909837]|12909837  |
#+--------------------------------+------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: I tried to do it as follow: `df_transf_2 = df_transf_1.withColumn("products_list", regexp_replace('products_basket','\[|\]',''))` `df_transf_2 = df_transf_2.withColumn("products_list", array("products_list"))` and then used `explode("products_list")` but it didn't work... why applying `array()` in this case does not work and should use `split("products_list",", ")` instead? Note that I got the same schema that you got before explode..

Comment: you have to call `split()` after the `regexp_replace`. Calling `array` is not appropriate here.

Comment: Yes I know it's not appropriate since it didn't lead to the expected output, but why?  I supposed that after making all elements of `products_basket` in the format of `'ghhjj23','123546',12356` when I apply array, it will add the brackets and explode will return new row for each element.

Comment: If you apply `array()` to a string, it will become an array with one element (the string). The `array()` function has no knowledge that the commas should be used as delimiters. If you call split, it will split the string into multiple elements and return an array. Does that make sense?

Comment: One potentially confusing aspect is that `array("products_basket", regexp_replace(r"(^\[)|(\]$)|(')", ""))` and `split("products_basket", regexp_replace(r"(^\[)|(\]$)|(')", ""), " ,")` will both *print* the same way to the console if you call `show()`, but the underlying data is different. The latter is what you want and the former is just an array with one string.

Comment: I applied your proposed solution to the dataframe (not sample) and it didn't work, produced explode as it produce when I applied `array()` means treating as one element all the array.. and after the split, `show()` gives an output without the space after comma.. trying to understand why.

Comment: @SarahData maybe that's because I split on `", "` when you want to just split on `","` (no space). It's hard to say without seeing your actual data, but it seems like the string is not being split because the pattern is not matching. You can also pass in regex patterns to split like `",(\s+)?"` which means a comma followed by optional whitespace.

Comment: yes, you're right, I went back again to split() function params and verified what it takes as input and the column previous step (after applying only `regexp_replace`) and understood that it should be `","` not `", "`. Thanks!